# Multiple dataset in Plotmatrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, plotmatrix

I have 1331 entries of 4 dimensional data in DataSet 1.
I also have 1331 entries of 4D data in Dataset 2.
I need to plot these datasets together in one plotmatrix using different colours.
How to do that ?
This is what i have tried so far

```
plotmatrix([w01 ,w02, w03,w04]);hold on
plotmatrix([w11 ,w12, w13,w14]);
```

It works well in the case of scatter plot

```
scatter3(w01 ,w02, w03,'filled')
hold on;
scatter3(w11 ,w12, w13,'filled');
hold on;
scatter3(w21 ,w22, w23,'filled');
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post some code snippets that you have tried...

Comment: Hi I have added code snippets

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else wonders, gplotmatrix is your friend.
Try this:

```
V1 = rand(100,3);         % a random vector
V2 = sin(V1);             % a function of V1
groups = (V2(:,1)>0.3)*1; % defining groups for discriminating the variables.
gplotmatrix(V1,V2,groups)
```